# What is the better approach for implementing Manager & Repository

Tags: c#

Can you please provide suggestion on below implementation

I am trying to implement a generic approach for calling `Class2.Save()` method from `Class1.Process()` .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IClass2 c2= new Class2();                         
        Class1 c1 = new Class1(c2);
        c1.Process<Student>(new Student());
    }
}

public interface IClass1 {
    bool Process<T>(T t) where T : new();

}
public class Class1 : IClass1
{

    IClass2 _repo;
    public Class1(IClass2 repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public bool Process<T>(T t) where T :  new()
    {
         _repo.Save (t);
        return true;
    }
}

public interface IClass2 {
    void Save(Student e);
    void Save(Teacher e);
}
public class Class2 : IClass2
{
    public void Save(Student e)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Save(Teacher e)
    {
        return;
    }
}
public class Student { }

public class Teacher { }
```

I don't like to use reflections or casting .
Could anyone help in getting this resolved or suggest alternate approach.

Comment: Hi, your IClass1 seems to be nice an generic, with the ability to handle different input types. Have you tried taking a similar approach with Class2? If so what problems are you facing?

Comment: i want my Class2 to be specific. Basically `Class2` is similar to Repository, where the data is saved to DB .

Comment: This question is vague and lacks specifics... Generically do what. what are you trying to achieve, what are your use cases, why isn't this working, as it stands this question is too broad

Comment: How much does Save need to know about `Student` or `Teacher`? Could they implement a common interface `IPerson` and you can use that in a generic constraint or a single `Save(IPerson person)` method?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

I've changed the constraints rather than being method constraints to class constraints.
And have separate classes which both adhere to the Repository interface.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepository();
        IProcessor<Student> processor = new Processor<Student>(studentRepository);
        processor.Process(new Student());
    }
}

public interface IProcessor<T> where T : new()
{
    bool Process(T t);

}
public class Processor<T> : IProcessor<T> where T : new()
{
    IRepository<T> _repo;
    public Processor(IRepository<T> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public bool Process(T t)
    {
        _repo.Save(t);
        return true;
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : new()
{
    void Save(T e);
}

public class StudentRepository : IRepository<Student>
{
    public void Save(Student e)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class TeacherRepository : IRepository<Teacher>
{

    public void Save(Teacher e)
    {
        return;
    }
}


public class Student { }

public class Teacher { }
```

Comment: Whoops, typo, one second..

Comment: Fixed..........

Comment: i am kind of okay with this approach . The only think that is drawing me off is, Teacher & Student belong same Repository . I don't think there should be different repositories for Teacher & Student

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood your initial feedback I thought you wanted them to share the repository... let me think..

Comment: The more I think, the more it's probably best to have separate repositories. I don't think you'll easily have two separate methods whilst retaining the generic vibe.

If you need to share behaviour between the Student and Teacher repository consider having a base class. Or compose the repository from specific implementations. This would fit in more nicely with the SOLID design principals as well https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1033646/SOLID-Principle-with-Csharp-Example

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints (which seem a little artificial to me, although I've seen worse), you can achieve this without reflection, without casting, and without changing the generic nature of your `Process` method, simply by inverting the call direction so that the object that knows its own type can call the right method in the repository.

Start by declaring your domain objects to be "Saveable":

```
public interface ISaveable
{
    void Save(IClass2 repo);
}

public class Student : ISaveable
{ 
    public void Save(IClass2 repo) 
    {
        repo.Save(this);
    }
}

public class Teacher : ISaveable
{ 
    public void Save(IClass2 repo)
    {
        repo.Save(this);
    }
}
```

Now each domain object knows how to save itself. All you have to do is hand it a repository, which you can do in your `Process` method.

```
public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    IClass2 _repo;

    public Class1(IClass2 repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public bool Process<T>(T t) where T : ISaveable
    {
        t.Save(_repo);
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Full example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n205Gq)